# core/html_select set aria-selected Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I'm searching for a solution with the magento buildin way to create html select blocks, with **aria-required**.
I can display basic attributes like the id or the class for example, but not this attribute.

Here is my first essay:

```
$select = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select');
$select->setName($name)
       ->setClass($class)
       ->setId($id);
       ->setArialRequired($ariaRequired); //doesn't work
```

Here is my second essay:

```
$select = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select'); 
$select->setData(array(
    'name' => $name,
        'class' => $class,
        'id' => $id,
        'aria-required' => $ariaRequired //doesn't work
    ));
```